# Remove an item from a list and return the item

Tags: java, arraylist, lambda, java-stream

I have an `ArrayList` and I want to check if an element exist in the list and if it exist I want to remove it and return it.

I tried to use `removeIf` but it returns a `boolean` value.

How can I do that?

Thanks!

LE

I have a list of objects Test:

`private static List<Test> tests = new ArrayList<>();`

I have the method `public Test deleteById(long id) {}`.

What I want is to check if `tests` contains a test with `id` and if that is true I want to remove the object and return it.

Comment: Don't you already know the element to delete? Why do you want to return it?

Comment: I know the id of it.

Comment: Would you mind posting what you have tried so far?

Comment: If there isn't a list method that does exactly what you want, you can still iterate through your list and check each element explicitly.

Comment: @hev1 I edited the post.

Comment: If you want the value removed from the list, `remove(int index)` in `List` should be helpful; this returns the removed value rather than a boolean.

Comment: [A similar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/78222873/642706) labeled this “identify, remove, and return” action as “pluck”.  Seems like a fitting and handy verb for this.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to find an element by a certain predicate, remove it and return it, you can have a method like this:

```
public static <E> E findRemoveAndReturn(List<E> items, Predicate<? super E> predicate) {
    Iterator<E> iter = items.iterator();
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        E item = iter.next();
        if (predicate.test(item)) {
            iter.remove();
            return item;
        }
    }
    return null; // or throw an exception
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in two steps. First, iterate(or stream) the list and filter the elements that satisfy your condition. Then remove them all from the list.

```
List<String> elementsToBeRemoved = tests.stream()
        .filter(test -> test.getId().equals(id))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
tests.removeAll(elementsToBeRemoved);
```

If you want to remove the first matching element or when you know for sure only one will match, you can do lile,

```
Optional<String> elementToBeRemoved = tests.stream()
        .filter(test -> test.getId().equals(id))
        .findFirst();
elementToBeRemoved.ifPresent(tests::remove);
```

Comment: Thanks for your idea!

Answer (score 0):

Call collect(partitioningBy()) with the predicate that you would use in removeIf. The elements under true match the predicate, so you can return them. Those under false should replace the input collection.

Answer (score -1):

Just use ArrayList.contains(desiredElement). For example, if you're looking for the conta1 account from your example, you could use something like:

Edit: Note that in order for this to work, you will need to properly override the equals() and hashCode() methods. If you are using Eclipse IDE, then you can have these methods generated by first opening the source file for your CurrentAccount object and the selecting Source > Generate hashCode() and equals()...