# Pluck from a Java Collection using stream

Tags: java, collections

I want to know if there is an impementation of "plucking" elements from a `Collection` implementation based from a given `Predicate`, that is to remove said elements after retrieving. To visualize what I mean, consider this use case:

```
Set<Parent> parentSet = parentDao.getParents();
Set<Long> parentIdSet = parentSet.stream().map(Parent::getId).collect(Collectors.toSet())
Set<Child> childrenSet = childDao.getChildByParentIds(parentIdSet);

for (Parent parent : parentSet) {
   Set<Child> childrenOfThisParent = childrenSet
      .stream()
      .pluck((Child c) -> Objects.equals(parent.getId(), c.getParentId()))
      .collect(Collectors.toSet());

   parent.setChildren(childrenOfThisParent);
}

// At this line, childSet should be empty.
assert(childrenSet.isEmpty());
```

What I want is every iteration, after `Set<Child>` was filtered by its `parentId` and initialized to `childrenOfThisParent`, I want them to be removed from the `childSet` and get the `size()` of `childSet` reduced. By effect, the searching from `childSet` should be faster the next iteration. Although at this point, I have to benchmark to know if the faster search time will be significant.

Comment: Why? Nothing wrong with the way you have it. Modifying a collection while you're streaming it isn't likely to work.

Comment: Streams is not the right tool for modifying collections. Here's a simple implementation that uses Iterator: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63141104/1553851

Comment: If `childrenSet` can be modified, you can add `childrenSet.removeAll(childrenOfThisParent);`.

Answer (score 2):

Streams just don't support "in place" operations like modifying an existing collection. If you want to do this with streams, you would need to produce new collections. You can use the `partitioningBy` collector to separate the children set into "children of this parent" and "not children of this parent". Both of these are new collections, stored in a new `Map`.

```
for (Parent parent : parentSet) {
    var partitions =
        childrenSet.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(
                c -> Objects.equals(parent.getId(), c.getParentId()),
                Collectors.toSet()
            ));
    childrenSet = partitions.get(false);

    parent.setChildren(partitions.get(true));
}
```

This allocates a whole lot of new collections, so probably isn't worth it. You can consider doing the whole operation of "grouping children into their parents" in one stream, using `groupingBy`:

```
var childrenByParentId = childrenSet.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
    Child::getParentId,
    Collectors.toSet()
));
for (var parent: parentSet) {
    parent.setChildren(childrenByParentId.get(parent.getId()));
}
```

Comment: Thanks!! The `Collectors.groupingBy` seems worth noting, will include that on my benchmark tests.